# What's the equivalent of SVG's `stop-opacity` in CSS?

Tags: html, css, svg

I'm trying to convert this simple SVG gradient to CSS:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" id="Layer_2" data-name="Layer 2" width="107.097" height="26.024" viewBox="0 0 107.097 26.024">
  <defs>
    <style>
      .cls-1 {
        fill: url(#linear-gradient);
        stroke-width: 0px;
      }
    </style>
    <linearGradient id="linear-gradient" x1="795.61" y1="-6.181" x2="707.657" y2="35.941" gradientTransform="translate(-701.986 26.024) scale(1 -1)" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <stop offset="0" stop-color="#f0ce45" stop-opacity="0"/>
      <stop offset="1" stop-color="#fd00ac"/>
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
  <g id="Layer_1-2" data-name="Layer 1">
    <rect class="cls-1" x="0" y="0" width="107.097" height="26.024" transform="translate(107.097 26.024) rotate(-180)"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

But I can't find the equivalent of `stop-opacity` in CSS. From MDN docs:

> The stop-opacity attribute defines the opacity of a given color
> gradient stop.
>
> The opacity value used for the gradient calculation is the product of
> the value of stop-opacity and the opacity of the value of the
> stop-color attribute. For stop-color values that don't include
> explicit opacity information, the opacity is treated as 1.

There is a `stop-opacity` property in CSSm but it doesn't behave the same.

```css
.gradient {
  width: 200px;
  height: 20px;
  stop-opacity: 0;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #f1109b, #f0ce45)
}
```

```html
<div class="gradient">
</div>
```

How can I recreate that gradient in CSS?

Comment: Instead of #f0ce45 you may try to use rgba(253,0,172,0) where the last value represents the alpha channel with 0 being fully transparent. A value of 1 is fully opaque.

Comment: @enxaneta I've already tried it. Doesn't work.

Comment: You can only apply this property to  svg `<stop>`  elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `mask-image` and apply a gradient as the image.  However keep in mind that [it is not fully supported everywhere yet](https://caniuse.com/?search=mask%20image).

```css
.gradient {
  width: 200px;
  height: 20px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #f1109b, #f0ce45);
  
  -webkit-mask-image: linear-gradient(to left, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
  mask-image:         linear-gradient(to left, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
}
```

```html
<div class="gradient"></div>
```

Comment: The browser support is good enough for us. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

This question sent me into some kind of rabbit hole of re-learning CSS and SVG (or correcting my false beliefs thereof) and I'd like to preserve a memento here for future reference.  Same as @enxameta in comments, I thought that translating such simple linear gradient from SVG to CSS must be quite straightforward. There are two problems that prevents it to be … simply doable:

### 1: Hue of fully transparent colour does not affect CSS gradient

Honestly, I would have sworn that `linear-gradient(#FFF, #FFF0)` must be different from `linear-gradient(#FFF, #0000)`, but, in CSS gradients, it is not.

[image: two identical rectangles filled with vertical white-to-black gradient]

Neither in animations.

```css
div {
 text-align: center;
}
.bg ~ div {
 background-image: linear-gradient(to right, var(--c1), var(--c2));
}
.anim ~ div {
 background-image: none;
 animation: 1s a infinite alternate linear;
}
@keyframes a {
 from { background-color: var(--c1); }
 to { background-color: var(--c2); }
}
html {
 background-color: #000;
 color: snow;
}
```

```html
<p>To transparent white:
<span style="background-image: linear-gradient(#FFF, #FFF0)">&nbsp; &nbsp;</span>
<span style="background-image: linear-gradient(#FFF, #0000)">&nbsp; &nbsp;</span>
:to transparent black.


<p class="bg">CSS Gradients from fully opaque red…
<div style="--c1: #F00F; --c2: #0000;">…to fully transparent black</div>
<div style="--c1: #F00F; --c2: #FFF0;">…to fully transparent white</div>
<div style="--c1: #F00F; --c2: #F000;">…to fully transparent red</div>
<div style="--c1: #F00F; --c2: #0005;">…to almost transparent black</div>
<div style="--c1: #F00F; --c2: #FFF5;">…to almost transparent white</div>
<div style="--c1: #F00F; --c2: #F005;">…to almost transparent red</div>
<p class="anim">CSS Animations from fully opaque red…
<div style="--c1: #F00F; --c2: #0000;">…to fully transparent black</div>
<div style="--c1: #F00F; --c2: #FFF0;">…to fully transparent white</div>
<div style="--c1: #F00F; --c2: #F000;">…to fully transparent red</div>
<div style="--c1: #F00F; --c2: #0005;">…to almost transparent black</div>
<div style="--c1: #F00F; --c2: #FFF5;">…to almost transparent white</div>
<div style="--c1: #F00F; --c2: #F005;">…to almost transparent red</div>
```

Yes, it makes very little sense, especially compared to SVG, where gradient stops with `stop-opacity="0"` (or with colours of zero alpha) affect its surroundings. Another example, comparing SVG and CSS gradient:

[image: svg basically shows two hues blending, even if the second one is transparent in the end]

### 2: CSS gradients are positioned differently than SVG

In CSS "0%"/"100%" stop is the tangent that crosses closest/farthest corner and is perpendicular to angled gradient axis. Is SVG you basically throw a line segment somewhere and gradient lines are perpendicular to only that starting and ending on x1 y1 - x2 y2. So translating any non-orthogonal gradient could be also a challenge, since you have to re-compute and last offset stops with regard to dimensions (ratio) of target element.

[image: two rectangles with similar gradients, but sadly not identical]

---

Some garbaj produced along the way, for making illustrations above.

CSS VS SVG gradients:

```css
:root { color-scheme: dark;}
div { clear: left; }
svg,p { float: left; margin: 0; }
```

```html
<div>From 1 to 0</div>

<div> SVG with RGB #... + stop-opacity 1 0
<svg width="200" height="50" viewBox="0 0 200 50">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="g-1" x2="200" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <stop offset="0" stop-color="#0F0" stop-opacity="1"/>
      <stop offset="1" stop-color="#F0F" stop-opacity="0"/>
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
  <rect fill="url(#g-1)" width="100%" height="100%" />
</svg>
</div>
<div> SVG with RGBA rgba #...F #...0
<svg width="200" height="50" viewBox="0 0 200 50">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="g0" x2="200" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"  color-interpolation="sRGB">
      <stop offset="0" stop-color="#0F0F"/>
      <stop offset="1" stop-color="#F0F0"/>
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
  <rect fill="url(#g0)" width="100%" height="100%" />
</svg>
</div>
<div>
CSS with rgba #...F #...0
<p style="width: 200px; height: 50px; 
background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #0F0F, #F0F0)
"></p>
</div>
<div>
CSS with rgba #...F #FFF0 (!!!)
<p style="width: 200px; height: 50px; 
background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #0F0F, #FFF0)
"></p>
<div>
CSS with rgba #...F #0000 (!!!)
<p style="width: 200px; height: 50px; 
background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #0F0F, #0000)
"></p>
</div>



<div>From 0 to 1</div>

<div> SVG with RGB #... + stop-opacity 0 1
<svg width="200" height="50" viewBox="0 0 200 50">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="g1" x2="200" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <stop offset="0" stop-color="#0F0" stop-opacity="0"/>
      <stop offset="1" stop-color="#F0F" stop-opacity="1"/>
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
  <rect fill="url(#g1)" width="100%" height="100%" />
</svg>
</div>
<div> SVG with RGBA rgba #...0 #...F
<svg width="200" height="50" viewBox="0 0 200 50">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="g2" x2="200" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"  color-interpolation="sRGB">
      <stop offset="0" stop-color="#0F00"/>
      <stop offset="1" stop-color="#F0FF"/>
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
  <rect fill="url(#g2)" width="100%" height="100%" />
</svg>
</div>
<div>
CSS with rgba #...0 #...F
<p style="width: 200px; height: 50px; 
background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #0F00, #F0FF)
"></p>
</div>

<div>Fully opaque colours:</div>

<div> SVG with RGB #... + stop-opacity 1 1
<svg width="200" height="50" viewBox="0 0 200 50">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="g3" x2="200" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <stop offset="0" stop-color="#0F0" stop-opacity="1"/>
      <stop offset="1" stop-color="#F0F" stop-opacity="1"/>
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
  <rect fill="url(#g3)" width="100%" height="100%" />
</svg>
</div>
<div> SVG with RGBA rgba #...F #...F
<svg width="200" height="50" viewBox="0 0 200 50">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="g4" x2="200" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <stop offset="0" stop-color="#0F0F"/>
      <stop offset="1" stop-color="#F0FF"/>
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
  <rect fill="url(#g4)" width="100%" height="100%" />
</svg>
</div>
<div>
CSS with rgba #...F #...F
<p style="width: 200px; height: 50px; 
background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #0F0F, #F0FF)
"></p>
</div>



<div>33% dim colours:</div>

<div> SVG with RGB #... + stop-opacity .333 .333
<svg width="200" height="50" viewBox="0 0 200 50">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="g5" x2="200" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <stop offset="0" stop-color="#0F0" stop-opacity=".33333333"/>
      <stop offset="1" stop-color="#F0F" stop-opacity=".33333333"/>
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
  <rect fill="url(#g5)" width="100%" height="100%" />
</svg>
</div>
<div> SVG with RGBA rgba #...5 #...5
<svg width="200" height="50" viewBox="0 0 200 50">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="g6" x2="200" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <stop offset="0" stop-color="#0F05"/>
      <stop offset="1" stop-color="#F0F5"/>
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
  <rect fill="url(#g6)" width="100%" height="100%" />
</svg>
</div>
<div>
CSS with rgba #...5 #...5
<p style="width: 200px; height: 50px; 
background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #0F05, #F0F5);
"></p>
</div>

<div>33% to 66% colours:</div>

<div> SVG with RGB #... + stop-opacity .333 .666
<svg width="200" height="50" viewBox="0 0 200 50">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="g7" x2="200" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <stop offset="0" stop-color="#0F0" stop-opacity=".33333333"/>
      <stop offset="1" stop-color="#F0F" stop-opacity=".66666666"/>
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
  <rect fill="url(#g7)" width="100%" height="100%" />
</svg>
</div>
<div> SVG with RGBA rgba #...5 #...5
<svg width="200" height="50" viewBox="0 0 200 50">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="g8" x2="200" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <stop offset="0" stop-color="#0F05"/>
      <stop offset="1" stop-color="#F0Fa"/>
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
  <rect fill="url(#g8)" width="100%" height="100%" />
</svg>
</div>
<div>
CSS with rgba #...5 #...5
<p style="width: 200px; height: 50px; 
background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #0F05, #F0Fa);
"></p>
</div>


<div>66% colours:</div>

<div> SVG with RGB #... + stop-opacity .333 .666
<svg width="200" height="50" viewBox="0 0 200 50">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="g9" x2="200" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <stop offset="0" stop-color="#0F0" stop-opacity=".66666666"/>
      <stop offset="1" stop-color="#F0F" stop-opacity=".66666666"/>
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
  <rect fill="url(#g9)" width="100%" height="100%" />
</svg>
</div>
<div> SVG with RGBA rgba #...5 #...5
<svg width="200" height="50" viewBox="0 0 200 50">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="g10" x2="200" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" color-interpolation="linearRGB">
      <stop offset="0" stop-color="#0F0a"/>
      <stop offset="1" stop-color="#F0Fa"/>
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
  <rect fill="url(#g10)" width="100%" height="100%" />
</svg>
</div>
<div>
CSS with rgba #...5 #...5
<p style="width: 200px; height: 50px; 
background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #0F0a, #F0Fa);
"></p>
</div>

<div>
<p style="width: 200px; height: 50px; 
background: RGB(85 85 85);
"></p>
<p style="width: 200px; height: 50px; 
background: #555;
"></p>

</div>

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

OP's code iterated to the point where it should be identical, but ...

```css
html {
 background-color: black;
 color: snow;
}
:link { color: aqua; }
:visited { color: lime; }

svg {
 outline: 2px #0FF6 solid; /* to see viewport boundary*/
 overflow: visible; /* to see things outside viewport */
 margin: 2em;
 transform:scale(2);
 transform-origin: center left;
}
rect {
 stroke-width: 2px !important; /* To see if it matches the viewport or not */
 stroke: black;
}

body { white-space: pre; }
```

```html
Original SVG (with added surrounding white stops)
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" id="Layer_2" data-name="Layer 2" width="107.097" height="26.024" viewBox="0 0 107.097 26.024">
  <defs>
    <style>
      .cls-1 {
        fill: url(#linear-gradient);
        stroke-width: 0px;
      }
    </style>
    <linearGradient id="linear-gradient" x1="795.61" y1="-6.181" x2="707.657" y2="35.941" gradientTransform="translate(-701.986 26.024) scale(1 -1)" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <stop offset="0" stop-color="#FFF" stop-opacity="1"/>
      <stop offset="0" stop-color="#f0ce45" stop-opacity="0"/>
      <stop offset="1" stop-color="#fd00ac"/>
      <stop offset="1" stop-color="#FFF" stop-opacity="1"/>
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
  <g id="Layer_1-2" data-name="Layer 1">
    <rect class="cls-1" x="0" y="0" width="107.097" height="26.024" transform="translate(107.097 26.024) rotate(-180)"/>
  </g>
</svg>
<!-- y coords had to be lowered by 20px, IDK Y (no pun indended) -->
Original with css moved to attributes, and effective gradient path visualised:
<svg width="107.097" height="26.024" viewBox="0 0 107.097 26.024">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="linear-gradient2" x1="795.61" y1="-6.181" x2="707.657" y2="35.941" gradientTransform="translate(-701.986 26.024) scale(1 -1)" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <stop offset="0" stop-color="#FFF" stop-opacity="1"/>
      <stop offset="0" stop-color="#f0ce45" stop-opacity="0"/>
      <stop offset="1" stop-color="#fd00ac"/>
      <stop offset="1" stop-color="#FFF" stop-opacity="1"/>
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
  <rect fill="url(#linear-gradient2)" x="0" y="0" width="107.097" height="26.024" transform="translate(107.097 26.024) rotate(-180)" stroke-width="4" stroke="black"/>
 <line x1="795.61" y1="-6.181" x2="707.657" y2="35.941" transform="translate(-701.986 26.024) scale(1 -1) translate(0 -20)" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" stroke="lime"/>
</svg>


SVG un-flipizorized (transfroms recalculated and products applied directly)
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="107.097" height="26.024" viewBox="0 0 107.097 26.024" color-interpolation="sRGB">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="linear-gradient3" x1="5.671" y1="11.917" x2="93.624" y2="52.205" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <stop offset="0" stop-color="#FFF" stop-opacity="1"/>
      <stop offset="0" stop-color="#f0ce45" stop-opacity="0"/>
      <stop offset="1" stop-color="#fd00ac"/>
      <stop offset="1" stop-color="#FFF" stop-opacity="1"/>
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
  <rect fill="url(#linear-gradient3)" x="0" y="0" width="107.097" height="26.024"></rect>
  <line x1="5.671" y1="11.917" x2="93.624" y2="52.205" stroke="lime"></line>
</svg>


Div with CSS gradient. R.I.P. Yellow from the transparent stop.
<div style="
 outline: 2px #0FF6 solid;
 width: 107.097px; height: 26.024px;
 transform:scale(2);
 transform-origin: top left;
 margin: 2em;
 display: flex;
 place-items: center;
 justify-content: center;
 background-image: linear-gradient(114.4deg, #fff 0 8.5%, #f0ce4500 0, #fd00ac);
">
 <div style="border: 1px solid lime; width: 97.51919555664062px; height: 0; width; transform: translate(-4px, 20px) /* = lies */  rotate(24.4deg)"></div>
</div>

Div with CSS gradient. Yellow is back with help of second background with background-blend-mode. R.I.P. transparency
<div style="
 outline: 2px #0FF6 solid;
 width: 107.097px; height: 26.024px;
 transform:scale(2);
 transform-origin: top left;
 margin: 2em;
 display: flex;
 place-items: center;
 justify-content: center;
 background-image:
    linear-gradient(114.4deg, #fff 0 8.5%, #000000 0, #ffffff00)
,   linear-gradient(114.4deg, #fff 0 8.5%, #f0ce45 0, #fd00ac)
;
 background-blend-mode: multiply, normal;
">
 <div style="border: 1px solid lime; width: 97.51919555664062px; height: 0; width; transform: translate(-4px, 20px) /* = lies */  rotate(24.4deg)"></div>
</div>
```

(So with `background-blend-mode` in the last try I got pretty close to the goal (on black background it is indistinguishable from SVG), but lost the transparency, what renders it quite useless.)